# Why are Japanese song lyrics often so seemingly ungrammatical?

Tags: grammar, usage, syntax, song-lyrics

For example, Natsukawa Rimi's 島唄 has this has most of the verbs in plain 連用形 with no apparent reason:

> でいごの花が咲き　風を呼び　嵐が来た
>
> でいごが咲き乱れ　風を呼び　嵐が来た
>
> くり返す悲しみは　島渡る波のよう
>
> ウージの森であなたと出会い
>
> ウージの下で千代にさよなら
>
> 島唄よ　風に乗り　鳥とともに　海を渡れ
>
> 島唄よ　風に乗り　届けておくれ　私の涙  etc etc

君をのせて from Castle in the Sky has English word order:

> 父さんが残した 熱い想い /
> 母さんがくれた あのまなざし

The way I understood that line it is equivalent to

> 父さんが熱い思いを残した / 母さんがあのまなざしをくれた

though I might be wrong and this is just two noun phrases standing by themselves.

The most weird song that I often listen to is いつも何度でも from 千と千尋の神隠し. The first stanza:

> 呼んでいる　胸のどこか奥で /
> いつも心踊る　夢を見たい

I understand it as follows:

> 胸のどこか奥から　よんでいる。いつも心が踊ってる。夢を見たい。

Though I might be wrong.

Some of the lines are half-grammatical but have weird meanings (Words I filled in to understand in brackets):

> 繰り返すあやまちの　そのたび（だ。）ひとは
>
> ただ青い空の　青さを知る

(Yeah right, knowing that blue sky is blue.)

> 果てしなく（い？）　道は続いて見えるけれど
>
> この両手は　光を抱ける
>
> さよならのときの　静かな胸（がある）
>
> ゼロになるからだが　耳をすませる

(Why would a "body tending to zero" "fill up ears"? I'm reminded of http://what-if.xkcd.com/50/ ...)

Comment: Are you aware that the 連用形 can be used as continuative form? So from the very first example: 風を呼び　嵐が来た = 風を呼んで　嵐が来た.

Comment: Yes, the first line is understandable but ウージの森であなたと出会い is kind of weird.

Comment: I don't think it's weird. ウージの森であなたと出会い sounds like a polite rendering of ウージの森であなたと出会って

Comment: It is continuative but what follows?

Comment: As I see it -- a semicolon. And then another related clause. Continuative prevents the sentence from ending and ties the thoughts together ("In a forest of ウージ we met; under the ウージ we parted for all time")

Comment: hint: relative clauses

Comment: Japanese seems to enjoy ending sentences with nouns too - even in prose you get sentences like 「迷う主人公」 instead of 「主人公が迷う」.

Comment: @Sjiveru that smells like a relative clause.

Comment: @EricDong It is indeed, it's just outside of any main clause :P 「迷う主人公。」would be the entire sentence.

Comment: Hmm...  so what's ungrammatical in the above?

Comment: FYI the song is by the band The Boom, and Rimi Natsukawa just covered it.

Comment: Here the 連用形 ku-form in 果てしなく(い?)道は続いて見えるけれど works adverbial (ie modifying the verb action). To see that, we can interpret the phrase as "it continues in a manner of not ending."

Comment: "Why are Japanese song lyrics often so *seemingly* ungrammatical?" Probably because - with respect - your Japanese grammar is somehow lacking. (Don't take this the wrong way - so is mine!) Song lyrics, in English as well as in Japanese, include both formal and colloquial expressions, half-finished thoughts, poetic constructions, old-fashioned and modern slang, dialect, grammatically acceptable but nonsensical stories, native-speaker-level 'errors', and so on. Figuring out what's what is of course a very difficult task for a non-native speaker.

Comment: (It helps if you're very thorough and careful with your grammar. 青さを知る doesn't mean "knowing that it is blue", it means "being/becoming familiar with its blueness", for example. That is not the *state* of being blue, but the *quality* of its blueness.)

Comment: It also pays to remember that songwriting is not as bound by grammatical rules as normal speech is, and is far more artistic in how to uses language to paint a scene in the listener's imagination. The more you understand about how it works, the more it becomes more about expressing thoughts and feelings rather than if something is perfectly grammatical

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First example: Your misunderstanding as Earthling points out

Second example: Ending a sentence with a noun or noun phrase, which is very common in Japanese poetry or lyrics

Third example: Grammatically correct, though it uses the techniques like inversion of the word order and ending a sentence with a noun

I think, generally speaking, Japanese language, or we Japanese people, don't value logic or gramatical rules.

We value the feeling and the beauty in each words, especially in poems or songs.

That's why you feel weird for such a beautiful Japanese lyrics.

Answer (score -1):

It's sounds more poetical to distort the order a bit. I think Virginia Woolf's seemingly abrupt writing style has a similar effect.

For a native somehow it make sense - or there's no need to make any sense.

The lyric above paints beautiful sceneries in my head and triggers acute emotions.